# How can I tell if this is the user's first ever session? Parse.com (Android)

Tags: android, parse-platform, installation

Simple question but something I haven't been able to wrap my head around.

Can I run a query in such a way that I can tell if this is the user's first time using the app, using information from Parse.com's InstallationQuery method?

Comment: Try something like this, U can use one Boolean value and at the time of signup make it true and after login get the data then make it false. In ur code if Boolean is true first time. Next time onward false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about parse, but you can do this with shared preference in android
Shared preference will not be created a variable first time and set it to true during first load of app, and for subsequent load it can be set to false.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html
Next time when you uninstall the app, shared preference are automatically deleted.